# What is the meaning of "+" in wget progress bar?

Tags: wget

I'm downloading with `wget` using a slow link.
 Sometimes the progress bar looks like this:

```
15% [+++++++++++++++===>          ] 10,582,848  --.-K/s   in 82s
```

What is the meanig of "+"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Usually, we see that when we have stopped a download and the continued/resumed with it again. That way, we are downloading only portion which has not been downloaded already.

This happens when you use the -c switch. For example

```
$ wget https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf
53% [=======================>                       ] 531,834      444KB/s
```

And then continuing with below command

```
$ wget -c https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf
100%[++++++++++++++++++++++++======================>] 996,759      326KB/s   in 1.3s
```

Hope,this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: That's right. my situation is I have unstable connection so when the download stop and start each it show previous part with `+`

Comment: This illustrates a terrific way of downloading outside of unreliable browsers like Firefox